# How can count multiplie extensions

Tags: bash

how can I count all files in a directory but only with the file extensions .r0* and .r1*?

for one working this

```
ls -l /home/test/.r0* | wc -l
```

but for multiply?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets to match a set of characters.

```
ls -l /home/test/.r[01]* | wc -l
```

Note that this isn't matching the extension, it's matching the whole filename. If you want to match an extension, you need `*` before it.

```
ls -l /home/test/*.r[01]* | wc -l
```

Comment: Count goes wrong for files with newlines. You can use `find ... exec echo "x" \; | wc -l`